# How to create a function with a parameter to be passed

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I’m just trying to create a function with a parameter, but it says that the parameter is undefined.

It’ll be clearer with the example:

```js
const txt = ["Some text here"];
let textPosition = 0;
const speed = 25;

function typeWriter(element) {
  document.getElementById("paragraph1").innerHTML = element[0].substring(0, textPosition);
  if(textPosition++ != element[0].length) {
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  } else {
    CallButton.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
};

typeWriter(txt);
```

```html
<span id="paragraph1"></span>
```

So I’m clearly doing something wrong here, but I do not know what and why.

The code should simply insert in `paragraph1` the string in the `txt` `array` in a typewriter style. It is working when I replace `element` with `txt`.

But since I need to call the same function multiple times for different text, so different arrays with different text in each, I need to pass a parameter, so that I can reuse the function.

```js
const txt = ["Some text here"];
let textPosition = 0;
const speed = 25;

function typeWriter() {
  document.getElementById("paragraph1").innerHTML = txt[0].substring(0, textPosition);
  if(textPosition++ != txt[0].length) {
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  } 
};

typeWriter();
```

```html
<span id="paragraph1"></span>
```

Comment: `setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);` there won't be any arguments passed, when called here.

Comment: Why? You mean that the function is actually called with `setTimeout`?

Comment: It's a recursion, basically it keeps calling itself with a small delay (speed) until the base case is reached `textPosition++ === txt[0].length` .

Comment: Ok but why can’t I pass arguments? What would be a solution to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 1):

Replace setTimeout callback with arrow function passing element

```js
const txt = ["Some text here"];
let textPosition = 0;
const speed = 25;

function typeWriter(element) {
  document.getElementById("paragraph1").innerHTML = element[0].substring(0, textPosition);
  if(textPosition++ != element[0].length) {
    setTimeout(() => typeWriter(element), speed);
  } else {
    CallButton.classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
};

typeWriter(txt);
```

```html
<span id="paragraph1"></span>
```

Comment: It’s just another element of the code that shouldn’t impact anything, but I put it there in case someone would spot a typo/mistake/etc.